# Collision Detection In Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, collision, unityscript

I am working on 3D fighting game.I have two character with their animation.I have applied character controller and character controller script which i have customized. I have two button one to move farword and one to move backword..And four button to play different animation just like make a punch, hit a leg etc. Upto that its work perfactly fine.
Now I have use capsule object with their capsule collider as a child of different bones. Like i have place one capsule object with their collider the child of left hand bone.SO where the bone move that object will move..
I have also place a capusle on the second player body which i place below the head and above the legs its mean it place in the chest erea. I have also used Rigid body having no gravity and onTrigger function clicked in all capsule obects.. Now i want  that when my first player hand touch the second player main body in which capsule is place it will call a function.But in the script it will not call..I dont know what is the problem..Can any body guide me. Here is my script

```
public function Start() : void {
f_inAirStartTime = Time.time;
}
//Checking if the character hit the ground (collide Below)
public function IsGrounded () : boolean {
return (c_collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.CollidedBelow);
}
//Getting if the character is jumping or not
public function IsJumping() : boolean {
return b_isJumping;
}
//Checking if the character is in the air more than the minimum time
//This function is to make sure that we are falling not walking down slope
public function IsAir() : boolean {
return (f_inAirTime > f_minAirTime);
}
//Geting if the character is moving backward
public function IsMoveBackward() : boolean {
return b_isBackward;
}
public function Update() : void {
//Get Main Camera Transform
var cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
//Get forward direction of the character
v3_forward = cameraTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
v3_forward.y = 0; //Make sure that vertical direction equals zero
// Right vector relative to the character
// Always orthogonal to the forward direction vector
v3_right = new Vector3(v3_forward.z, 0, -v3_forward.x);

//Get Horizontal move - rotation
var f_hor : float ;//= Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
if(backword==true)
{
f_hor=1;
backword=false;
}
if(farword==true)
{
f_hor=-1;
farword=false;
}











//Get Vertical move - move forward or backward
var f_ver : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
//If we are moving backward
if (f_ver < 0) {
b_isBackward = true;
} else {
b_isBackward = false;
}
//Get target direction
var v3_targetDirection : Vector3 = (f_hor * v3_right) + (f_ver * v3_forward);
//If the target direction is not zero - that means there is no button pressing
if (v3_targetDirection != Vector3.zero) {
//Rotate toward the target direction
v3_moveDirection = Vector3.Slerp(v3_moveDirection, v3_targetDirection, f_rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
v3_moveDirection = v3_moveDirection.normalized; //Get only direction by normalizing our target vector
} else {
v3_moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
}
//Checking if character is on the ground
if (!b_isJumping) {
//Holding Shift to run
//if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightShift)) {
if(Left_punch_anim){


b_isRun = true;

f_moveSpeed = runSpeed;
//Right_punch_anim=false;
} else {
b_isRun = false;
f_moveSpeed = speed;
}
//Press Space to Jump
if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) {
f_verticalSpeed = jumpSpeed;
b_isJumping = true;
}
}
//Debug.Log(controller.velocity.sqrMagnitude+"magniture");

// Apply gravity
if (IsGrounded()) {
f_verticalSpeed = 0.0; //if our character is grounded
b_isJumping = false; //Checking if our character is in the air or not
f_inAirTime = 0.0;
f_inAirStartTime = Time.time;
} else {
f_verticalSpeed -= gravity * Time.deltaTime; //if our character in the air
//Count Time
f_inAirTime = Time.time - f_inAirStartTime;
}
// Calculate actual motion
var v3_movement : Vector3 = (v3_moveDirection * f_moveSpeed) + Vector3 (0, f_verticalSpeed, 0); // Apply the vertical speed if character fall down
v3_movement *= Time.deltaTime;
// Move the controller
c_collisionFlags = controller.Move(v3_movement);
//Play animation
if (b_isJumping) {
if (controller.velocity.y > 0 ) {
animation[jumpPoseAnimation.name].speed = jumpAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(jumpPoseAnimation.name, 0.1);
} else {
animation[fallPoseAnimation.name].speed = fallAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(fallPoseAnimation.name, 0.1);
}
} else {
if (IsAir()) { // Fall down
animation[fallPoseAnimation.name].speed = fallAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(fallPoseAnimation.name, 0.1);
} else {
if(controller.velocity.sqrMagnitude < 0.1) {
   if(Left_punch_anim)
   {

   animation[leftanimAnimation.name].speed = runAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(leftanimAnimation.name, 0.5);
Left_punch_anim=false;
idlemode=true;

   }
   else
   if(Right_punch_anim)
   {

   animation[rightanimAnimation.name].speed = runAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(rightanimAnimation.name, 0.5);
Right_punch_anim=false;
idlemode=true;

   }
   else
  { 
//Debug.Log(controller.velocity.sqrMagnitude+"hjgkjgkjg");
animation[idleAnimation.name].speed = idleAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(idleAnimation.name, 0.1);
}
} else { //Checking if the character walks or runs
if (b_isRun) {
//Debug.Log("In the run animation");
animation[leftanimAnimation.name].speed = runAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(leftanimAnimation.name, 0.1);
} else {
animation[walkAnimation.name].speed = walkAnimationSpeed;
animation.CrossFade(walkAnimation.name, 0.1);
}
}
}
}
if(idlemode)
{

}
//Update rotation of the character
if (v3_moveDirection != Vector3.zero) {
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(v3_moveDirection);
}
}
public function OnControllerColliderHit(hit:ControllerColliderHit)
{
    //     Debug.Log("Collision have been enter");
    }   

/*public function OnTriggerEnter(other:Collider)
{

Debug.Log(other.gameObject.name);
}*/
public function OnCollisionEnter(other:Collision)
{
Debug.Log("collision is enter");
}
function OnTriggerEnter(col:Collider)
{
Debug.Log(col.gameObject.name); 

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alright. I assume that you get neither the OnCollisionEnter nor the OnTriggerEnter call.

Ensure, that the scripts with these methods are on the actual GameObject, that has the collider-component.

OnCollisionEnter-Reference:

> "Note that collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached."

To sum up: OnCollisionEnter is only called if you actually use the physics system for moving the objects around due to forces, collisions etc.

If you want to just register a hit without it causing movement via the physics-system, you can use the OnTriggerEnter.
In this case, the rigidbody must be on the moving object, and at least one of the involved colliders must be set to isTrigger.

Also ensure that the layers are set to collide in  projectSettings->Physics.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks sune for Your replay...Actually on my character i have character controller which apply on the whole mesh and I have different capsule collider on different body parts.I am not using any phsyics i just want when these two character collide then the function will trigger up..I have use OnTriggerEnter function...But its not working

Comment: I did't understand your last line..."Also ensure that the layers are set to collide in projectSettings->Physics."

Comment: In the Unity top bar - click edit->projectSettings->Physics. This will show you a matrix in the inspector, taht allows you to select which layers are to collide with which other layers.