# Collision with Capsule Collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript

I am using two character.I am using Character controler on both of them.But i have place capsule and capsule collider on these character as well. But i want the collision will detect when capsule are collided with each other.I am using OnTriggerEnter function.And both of these character has rigidbody having no graivty and IsTrigger clicked...But my on TriggerFunction is not working...

Comment: Please don't double post.  This sounds almost exactly like your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240161/collision-detection-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the tickmark `IsTrigger` on either of the `Collider` and the `OnTriggerEnter` method should be in the second object, which is not a trigger (It can be a trigger too).

PS:
from [OnTriggerEnter script reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) -

> Note that trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also
>   has a rigid body attached.

Comment: thanks Creator for your reply...Istrigger is clicked on both object..But it will call only when two character controller bounderies hit with each other.But I am not using character controller to for collision..I want when my capsule collider bodies hit each other then onTrigger function will call...But its not happining...:(

Comment: I have attach Rigidbodies to both of the object having no gravity...But still its not working..